# Mix SRAM eTap with GRX Group

Tags: shimano, sram

I have a GRX810 2x groupset. I'm thinking about changing the shifting system to SRAM eTap, but retain the GRX braking system and the crankset. I tried to get any information for the GRX group but could not maybe since it is quite new.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by 'changing the shifting system to eTap but stick to the braking system'. You can't separate the two systems.

If you change shifters you are changing the brake levers. Shimano and SRAM hydraulic brake levers and calipers are utterly incompatible as they use different hydraulic fluids (SRAM DOT fluid, Shimano mineral oil).

If you are replacing the shifters/brake levers why not replace the calipers too?

Shimano provides extensive info on all their bicycle products. Start here https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/. Specific GRX810 info is here https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/rx810/mech_2x11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the whole GRX810 Set and want to change to eTap. I thought I could safe some money by not replacing the crankset and the calipers. That was the intention of my question.

Comment: @ruedi you might be able to use the crank, but everything will be guaranteed to work better if you swap the whole group. If you want electronic shifting there is a 810 DI2 group which would all you to keep calipers, crank chain, cassette etc.

Comment: That is right. But I do not want anything conserning shifting inside my frame and with the Di2 this is not possible as far as I see. The eTab is completely outside that is what I am looking for. Thank you for your hint though!

Comment: @ruedi I’d like to emphasize Argenti’s statement on incompatibility. Everything in a brake, including the rubber seals, is designed for a *specific* type of fluid. SRAM uses something called DOT 5, which is corrosive. Shimano uses a type of mineral oil. You put DOT 5 in something not designed for it, and it would surely corrode the seals. If you tried it, you would destroy the calipers and not even have those to resell. Also, properly installed Di2 won’t rattle in a gravel bike (personal experience).

Comment: @Weiwen: Thanks for highlightening the point. A am aware of this. It is not abouit ratteling. I just do not want to remove the bottom bracket and other thinks if anything crashes. In my case atm I even have to remove the bottom bracket to renew the shifting cables...

Comment: @ruedi I was confused, and I thought you had GRX Di2. I see you specified the model number of the mech version.

Comment: It's even unlikely you can properly re-use the crankset: GRX uses a different chainline than SRAM's 2x systems.

Answer (score -1):

while this was a question from 3 years ago, at Melbourne's Homemade bikeshow the people at Auren bikes have done exactly this.

SRAM AXS RD and the internals from the SRAM shifter paired up with GRX Shifters and Shimano brakes.

Where there is a will there is a way.

Comment: This does not sound like *exactly this*. The question wants to pair SRAM shifters and Shimano brakes.

Comment: Are you able to provide more info on how they did it and/or photos?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain _____fill_in_here________. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: "Where there is a will there is a way" is wrong on the merits. Yes, it can be literally correct, but the answer implies that someone stripped the electronics from a GRX shifter, and transplanted the electronics from a SRAM AXS shifter. This won't be practical for an average cyclist. And it's also possible the OP had *mechanical* GRX. There's also no proof (yet?) that Auren Bikes did this, either on their Insta or the show's Insta.

Comment: Check the first Auren Bikes photo in this gallery of the Australian Handmade Bicycle Show, 2023. It definitely has GRX shifters, and the RD looks like it a) lacks a wire and b) is possibly a SRAM AXS RD. https://escapecollective.com/handmade-bicycle-show-australia-2023-part-four/